# Android vs iPhone vs Windows Phone vs Others as a platform for internal business software

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, symbian

I am evaluating smartphone operating systems and hardware platforms (and in a roundabout way, mobile carriers) to see which one would be the most suitable for delivering custom business software. Our applications will only be used by internal employees. Here are some features and bullet points that influence the selection:

- Our apps will need access to about 1 GB of proprietary data. We could use an embedded SQL database, but for speed, our preference is to have access to some kind of file system, or possibly SD card storage.
- This data is mostly read-only on the mobile side. But we do need to update it regularly from corporate data sources. This could happen over the wire, or by docking to a workstation, or by taking an SD card out, and updating the data it on a PC.
- Our applications will be graphical visualizations of the proprietary data. The data is used in a ag/biotech/research environment.
- Code execution speed is critical.
- The 1GB of data will be shared across multiple applications that we create.
- Devices will be used worldwide, but by a relatively small number of users (~1000).
- Users work both indoors and outdoors doing agricultural research. While indoors, they have good network connectivity. While outdoors, connectivity is poor. They also travel a fair bit throughout the year.
- Our development staff has lots of experience with C# and .net (mostly windows forms) and some exposure to C++ and java. We have done some mobile development with .net, some palm OS stuff years ago, and a few developers have tinkered with learning iPhone development.
- Being cross platform and not tied to a specific wireless provider or software platform would be desirable. But vendor lock-in seems to be the name of the game these days.
- We will deploy applications ourselves, and have no need for app stores and the like.

I know that is a lot to digest. So what is my question? I would like opinions on which devices and platforms are the most suitable for what we are doing. I would also like developers who have developed internal business software for these platforms to chime in and share what they have learned.

Comment: Here are my initial thoughts :

1 The iPhone software and hardware platforms are too close minded for us.
2 Android devices seem to have what we want, but java would be a bit of a learning curve.
3 Windows Phone 7 would be the easiest platform for us to code for right now. But it may not be the best platform for our users. 
4 Can MonoTouch, MonoDroid, and .net give us a viable cross platform solution?

Comment: I went from a .Net background straight into Java dev for Android and had zero problems.  I found that .Net having so many more features and intricacies (LINQ being the perfect example) that it was easy to strip away what I needed, learn some basic stuff like threading in Java, and I was off and running.  Especially if you have WPF and SL exp, the UI in XML thing is very familiar (and again, less features = easier learning curve).  I have heard that MonoWhatever will paint you into a corner eventually with unsupported functionality, but I don't have the exp to back that up.

Comment: Java isn't going to be a problem, it's just syntax, and all the languages have relatively similar syntax to start with anyway. The biggest problem is the new environment, and that's going to be there with all of them.
If you want external storage, your only real choice is Android. iPhone and Windows both have restricted internal only at the moment.
And for deploying them yourself, I'm not sure about Windows, but iPhone you won't be able to do that without jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If blackberry's traditional corporate integration features are of interest you might look at that.

Otherwise android is probably your best bet in terms of currently popular platforms (some of the more traditional linux-based phone stacks might be technically preferable, but their future is uncertain).

You have full authority to independently deploy applications

Most Android phones either accept an SD card up to 32GB or give you 16GB of built in storage.  You can use wifi or mount it to a pc as a usb disk for updates (in addition of course to mobile data)

While android promotes java development, its not actually necessary to use this except for application lifecycle and user interface purposes.  You can write all your core code in C using most normal unprivileged unix-type capabilities, or in C++ - though there's a slowly shrinking list of limitations on C++.  OpenGL ES is available for display.  And actually, the latest version of android offers the necessary java wrappers already written to enable you to create a C/C++ application without writing any java code yourself.

Another reason for going with android would be the potential of deploying your own customized device, not necessarily a smartphone but perhaps a tablet/pda or ruggedized system at some point in the future.

Also, if the bulk of your code is C/C++ and your developers use reasonable abstractions, you should be able to create a project that will build as both a desktop and a mobile application, by wrapping the core code with either UI and application container.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect hardware availability to play a part in the decision. Depending on quite what is being done with the devices outdoors you may need to consider ruggedised devices and/or devices with a high [IP Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code).

If this is the case, I'd recommend considering using Windows Mobile (6.x).
Yes, Mobile, Not Phone 7.

It can meet all your requirements listed above plus there are a large nubmer of different devices available.
While it's time as a consumer platform has wained, this is exactly the type of scenario this platform was intended for.

Also note that this product has not reached end of life but will be called [Windows Embedded Handheld](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/handheld/overview.mspx) going forward.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one for sure.

The first thing I would rule out is the iOS platform:

- Closed mindset
- Strict publishing rules, even for internal enterprise development
- Objective C / Cocoa Touch is a PITA to learn.
- Limited and Expensive Devices

Symbian is a very popular platform but for only one reason, cheapest smartphone OS out there, I think that while it is good, all other platforms are better, and even more importantly will get even better over time, Symbian is finally starting to loose ground.

Windows Phone: I havent done propper research but to me winMO seems better for business solutions, windows phone is more a end consumer product, oriented to the social networking and online boom.

Blackberry: Great at keeping your data safe, while not as good as iOS or Android as a platform it offers many things that no other hardware does, if you manage critically secret info, look into blackberry.

Android: My *personal* current favorite, the API is easy to use with basically infinte tools, its as flexible as iOS without all the crazy restrictions. There are 50+ devices that would make sense to buy for what you want ranging from $200 to $800, you choose how good you want the hardware to be. Google is also putting crazy amounts of work into this so expect it to get better and better, just so you get an idea, Android had 3,5% market share for 3Q09 and has 25,5% 3Q10. Growth like that is something rarely seen, and *to me* indicates that Android is platform on which it would be smart to bet on.

Comment: There are no rules for enterprise deployment on iOS devices.  You could even use private API's if you wished (though you run the risk of system updates breaking software which is why you should be careful doing so).

Comment: Yes there are, you need to pay 299$ & a Dun & Bradstreet number to be able to "Distribute your proprietary, in-house applications to employees or members of your organization. The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is available to companies with a Dun & Bradstreet number". Taken from: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: Which any company can have.  I have a small consulting company and I have a D&B number, am switching over to the enterprise program.  That is a recent change, you used to have to have 500 employees.  There are no rules for deployment when you are in the enterprise program (which I should have clarified).  $299 is a negligible cost for any business looking to deploy even a small number of devices.

Comment: How are those not restrictions? What does Android, in comparison, ask for to deploy in house apps?

Comment: They aren't restrictions because they don't affect your ability to develop software.  They are overhead at most.  For Android you also do not have any restrictions, but you do have overhead - you have to buy devices to test on.  It's just the amount of overhead in question...

Comment: Sorry, while I do understand your point of view, I cant really agree with you. What you mention as overhead would actually make me choose another platform, I guess its just a matter of personal liking. Here's to actually managing to have a smart discussion over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Monotouch on iPhone would probably be your best path - especially for corporate software where you might not need the full capabilities of the platform.  In speed critical code you could fall back to Objective-C or even C as needed.

One of the reasons I would advocate iOS over other platforms is:

1) Stronger frameworks.  Android has pretty good frameworks but they don't have anything like CoreData, which could be very handy for speeding enterprise development.  There are also other third party frameworks like CorePlot that could be really useful producing in-app graphs and CoreAnimation has a lot of possibility for data visualization.  There's also the Accelerate framework which leverages the device GPU (if present) to speed calculations for things like Linpack and FFT work.

2) Full ability to deploy what you want - there are no restrictions on iOS enterprise deployment, and anyone with a D&B number can be in the iOS Enterprise development program.  So you don't have to worry about the app store.

3) Leveraging existing app base - although it's vague as to what you are trying to do, there's a good chance you can make use of some third party applications in your workflow, where the much larger and quality-oriented iPhone app store could be a benefit.  URL and file type handlers allow applications to pass data between them.

4) Third party cases and accessories - Otterbox makes cases for the Touch, iPhone and iPad, but basically there are a ton of third party options for chargers, car mounting kits, etc.

The iPad seems like it would work pretty well for your needs, either the 3G model (which you can use a micro-sim with) or paired with a MiFi kind of device (like the Verizon pairing).

Monotouch does cost money to use but it would probably give your developers a real speed boost in development time, and let them focus on learning the frameworks.